# Refactoring Methods using Nested Enums

Tags: java, enums, refactoring

I'm working on a project that simulates a heavily modified DnD 3.5. Right now, I'm working on Professions (classes, but I didn't want there to confusion with `class`), especially regarding saving throws. Right now, I have an enum for each Profession, and each member uses a constructor that specifies whether each kind of save is good or poor, which is represented in nested enums. However, the methods that calculate the modifiers are basically identical, except they use a `switch` on different saving throws.

Is there a way of refactoring a method to accept a parent enum as one of a method's arguments, and then do checks on a nested enum's value?

```
public enum Profession {
    BARBARIAN   (WillSave.POOR, FortitudeSave.GOOD, ReflexSave.POOR),
    BARD        (WillSave.GOOD, FortitudeSave.POOR, ReflexSave.GOOD),
    CLERIC      (WillSave.GOOD, FortitudeSave.GOOD, ReflexSave.POOR);


    private static int goodSaveModifier(int level) {
        return ((level / 2) + 2);
    }

    private static int poorSaveModifier(int level) {
        return (level / 3);
    }



    /**
     * Generates the given ProfessionType
     *
     * @param wil <code>WillSave.STRONG</code> if profession has a good will save, or
     * <code>POOR</code> otherwise
     * @param fort <code>FortitudeSave.STRONG</code> if profession has a good fortitude save, or
     * <code>POOR</code> otherwise
     * @param ref <code>ReflexSave.STRONG</code> if profession has a good reflex save, or
     * <code>POOR</code> otherwise
     */
    Profession(WillSave wil, FortitudeSave fort, ReflexSave ref) {
        will = wil;
        fortitude = fort;
        reflex = ref;
    }


    /**
     * Calculates the Profession's Fortitude modifier.
     *
     * @param level Character's current level
     * @return Profession's modifier of the WillSave save
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException If saving throw strength isn't valid
     */
    public int willModifier(int level) {
        int modifier;

        switch(will) {
            case GOOD:
                modifier = goodSaveModifier(level);
                break;
            case POOR:
                modifier = poorSaveModifier(level);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Save type " + will.name() + " doesn't exist.");
        }

        return modifier;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the Profession's Fortitude modifier.
     *
     * @param level Character's current level
     * @return Profession's modifier of the FortitudeSave save
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException If saving throw strength isn't valid
     */
    public int fortitudeModifier(int level) {
        int modifier;

        switch(fortitude) {
            case GOOD:
                modifier = goodSaveModifier(level);
                break;
            case POOR:
                modifier = poorSaveModifier(level);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Save type " + fortitude.name()
                                                            + " doesn't exist.");
        }

        return modifier;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the Profession's Reflex modifier.
     *
     * @param level Character's current level
     * @return Profession's modifier of the ReflexSave save
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException If saving throw strength isn't valid
     */
    public int reflexModifier(int level) {
        int modifier;

        switch(reflex) {
            case GOOD:
                modifier = goodSaveModifier(level);
                break;
            case POOR:
                modifier = poorSaveModifier(level);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Save type " + reflex.name()
                                                            + " doesn't exist.");
        }

        return modifier;
    }


    private final WillSave will;
    private final FortitudeSave fortitude;
    private final ReflexSave reflex;




    private enum WillSave {
        GOOD, POOR;
    }

    private enum FortitudeSave {
        GOOD, POOR;
    }

    private enum ReflexSave {
        GOOD, POOR;
    }
}
```

All I can think of is having yet another nested enum, let's say `SavingThrow.WILL` as an example, and I can't think of how to then specify which throw in the parameter since the signature in this case would then be something like `calculateModifier(SavingThrow save, int level) : int`, and it won't work. Here's my attempt anyway, although it will obviously just throw the save such as `WILL` instead of its value such as `GOOD`. Is there a way of refactoring something like this cleanly?

```
public int calculateModifier(SavingThrow save, int level) {
    int modifier;

    switch(save) {
        case GOOD:
            modifier = goodSaveModifier(level);
            break;
        case POOR:
            modifier = poorSaveModifier(level);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Save type " + save.name()
                                                        + " doesn't exist.");
    }

    return modifier;
}


private final SavingThrow.WILL will;
private final SavingThrow.FORTITUDE fortitude;
private final SavingThrow.REFLEX reflex;



private enum SavingThrow {
    WILL {
        GOOD, POOR;
    },

    FORTITUDE {
        GOOD, POOR;
    },

    REFLEX {
        GOOD, POOR;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you have exactly 3 same enums named differently. Here is the refactored code:

```
public enum Profession {
    BARBARIAN   (Save.POOR, Save.GOOD, Save.POOR),
    BARD        (Save.GOOD, Save.POOR, Save.GOOD),
    CLERIC      (Save.GOOD, Save.GOOD, Save.POOR);

    private final Save will;
    private final Save fortitude;
    private final Save reflex;

    Profession(Save will, Save fortitude, Save reflex) {
        this.will = will;
        this.fortitude = fortitude;
        this.reflex = reflex;
    }

    public int willModifier(int level) {
        return will.modifier.apply(level);
    }

    public int fortitudeModifier(int level) {
        return fortitude.modifier.apply(level);
    }

    public int reflexModifier(int level) {
        return reflex.modifier.apply(level);
    }

    private enum Save {

        GOOD(level -> level / 2 + 2),
        POOR(level -> level / 3);

        private final Function<Integer, Integer> modifier;

        Save(Function<Integer, Integer> modifier) {
            this.modifier = modifier;
        }

    }

}
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: This is beautiful and you, sir, are a god. I'm still relatively new to Java, and I have almost no experience with Functional programming, so I would've never thought of this kind of solution, but this is a perfect example of how powerful it really is. Thank you :)